# input array sum with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have unknown quantity of inputs with array name and class

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[1]" class="sum" value="31">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[2]" class="sum" value="21">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[3]" class="sum" value="321">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[4]" class="sum" value="-31">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[5]" class="sum" value="31.12">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[6]" class="sum" value="0">
```

Question is how sum all values of those fields what i try is to use .each() and getElementByClassName but this wont work

Comment: could you show your not working code..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried using the each, it worked for me. Check if you used **parseFloat**...

If you have 'sum' as a class to define all the elements that must be calculated, below code should work....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function (index, element) {
        total = total + parseFloat($(element).val());
    });
    alert(total);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Iterate over the matched elements and add their values together:

```
var total = 0;
$( ".sum" ).each( function(){
  total += parseFloat( $( this ).val() ) || 0;
});
```

I'm using `$.each()` to iterate over all items matching the `.sum` class, and then extracting the `value` attribute with `.val()`. Once we have that value, we need to make sure that it is numerical so I've used `parseFloat()`. If `parseFloat()` returns a falsy value, `0` will be used.

References:

- [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: parseInt(31.12).. would be 31, but its 31.12..?

Comment: I'd also use $(this).val() or this.value instead of attr.

Answer (score 3):

```
var totalSum = 0;
$('.sum').each(function () {
    totalSum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/K8ZTb/)

Comment: +1 for being the only one who correctly used parseFloat instead of parseInt

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
var total = 0;
$('.sum').each(function() {
total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) jQuery function to iterate `input.sum` elements will be enough.

```
var sum = 0;
$('input.sum').each(function() {
   var value = +this.value || 0;
   sum += value;
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cz688/)